# Segmentation fault and invalid size of 4?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure out the Solution to this problem for quite a while now and it is freaking me out. I know what they mean but I can't seem to figure out the problem in my code. I ran valgrind and it gave me this:

```
   LIST OF MOVIES:
==14740== Invalid read of size 4
==14740==    at 0x8049176: Movie::getGenreType() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049E30: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==  Address 0xbe92a154 is just below the stack ptr.  To suppress, use: --workaround-gcc296-bugs=yes
==14740== 
==14740== Invalid read of size 4
==14740==    at 0x804916A: Movie::getYear() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049E5A: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==  Address 0xbe92a150 is just below the stack ptr.  To suppress, use: --workaround-gcc296-bugs=yes
==14740== 
==14740== Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0x884f034, 0x804915c, 138775300)
==14740==    at 0x402D9A9: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14740==    by 0x40D8B17: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x40D93AF: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x8049E70: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740== 
==14740== Invalid read of size 4
==14740==    at 0x402DB26: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14740==    by 0x40D8B17: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x40D93AF: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x8049E70: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==  Address 0x884f024 is 4 bytes before a block of size 138,775,313 alloc'd
==14740==    at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14740==    by 0x40D77D3: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x8049E70: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740== 
==14740== Invalid read of size 4
==14740==    at 0x402DB18: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14740==    by 0x40D8B17: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x40D93AF: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x8049E70: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==  Address 0x884f018 is 16 bytes before a block of size 138,775,313 alloc'd
==14740==    at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14740==    by 0x40D77D3: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x8049E70: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740== 
==14740== 
==14740== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==14740==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x884EFFC
==14740==    at 0x402DB26: memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==14740==    by 0x40D8B17: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x40D93AF: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==14740==    by 0x8049E70: Interface::printMovieData(List*) (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x804939E: Control::addMovies() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8049288: Control::createMovieDataBase() (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==    by 0x8048C65: main (in /home/student/Documents/SoftwareEngineering/ASS3/mdb)
==14740==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==14740==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==14740==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==14740==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==14740==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==14740== 
==14740== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14740==     in use at exit: 138,775,357 bytes in 4 blocks
==14740==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 10 frees, 138,775,545 bytes allocated
==14740== 
==14740== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14740==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14740==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14740==      possibly lost: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==14740==    still reachable: 138,775,337 bytes in 3 blocks
==14740==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14740== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==14740== 
==14740== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14740== ERROR SUMMARY: 14 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is part of my code. If there are more information you will need, I will gladly provide them.

```
void List::addMovie(Movie* newMovie)
{ 
  if(newMovie==NULL)
    return;
  Node* currNode=head;
  Node* prevNode=NULL;
  Node* node= new Node(newMovie);

  if(currNode==NULL){
    head=node;
    tail=node;
    return;
  }
  while(currNode!=NULL){
      prevNode=currNode;
      currNode=currNode->next;
  }
    node->next=currNode;
    prevNode->next=node;
    node->prev=prevNode;
    tail=node;

}
```

function in the view/interface class:

```
void Interface::getMovieData(List* movieList)
{
  int num,choice,year;
  string title;
  cout<<"\nEnter the number of movies:   ";
  cin>>num;

  while (num > 0) {
    Movie newMovie;
    //m.movies[i] = new Movie();
    cout<<"\nEnter the next movie title:   "<<endl;
    cin>>title;
    cout<<"Enter the year:  "<<endl;
    cin>>year;

    cout<<"(1) "<< newMovie.getGenre(Movie::C_COMEDY)<<endl;
    cout<<"(2) "<< newMovie.getGenre(Movie::C_DRAMA)<<endl;
    cout<<"(3) "<< newMovie.getGenre(Movie::C_ACTION)<<endl;
    cout<<"(4) "<< newMovie.getGenre(Movie::C_HORROR)<<endl;
    cout<<"(5) "<< newMovie.getGenre(Movie::C_SF)<<endl;
    cout<<"(6) "<< newMovie.getGenre(Movie::C_ADVENTURE)<<endl;
    cout<<"(7) "<< newMovie.getGenre(Movie::C_WESTERN)<<endl;
    cout<<"Choose genre:  "<<endl;
    cin>>choice;

    newMovie.setMovieData(title, year,Movie::GenreType(choice - 1));
    cout<<newMovie.getTitle()<<endl;
    movieList->addMovie(&newMovie);
    --num;
  }

}
```

function in the control class:

```
void Control::addMovies(){
  List movieList;
  view.getMovieData(&movieList);
  server.update(Storage::ADD, &movieList);
  view.printMovieData(&movieList);
 // movieList.cleanupData();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you have a pointer to the list tail, why are you looping in the `addMovie` function? Also, after the loop `currNode` will always be `NULL`, so the assignment `node->next=currNode;` might as well be `node->next=NULL;`

Comment: Welcome to C++, enjoy the STL: it's your friend. Look at `std::list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One major problem is that you add pointers to local variables to your list:

```
while (num > 0) {
    Movie newMovie;

    ...

    movieList->addMovie(&newMovie);

    ...
}
```

In the above code, the variable `newMovie` is local not only to the function, but local inside the loop. That means that when the loop iterates, the `newMovie` object goes out of scope and a new `newMovie` object is created.

Storing pointers to these scoped variables means you have a list with pointers to lots of destroyed objects. Dereferencing those pointers leads to *undefined behavior*, and most likely lots of crashes.